# Camel bindy throwing null pointer exception when i use same positioned value multiple times

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, bindy

I'm using two DataFields with same positions for two different attributes. It is throwing null pointer exception.Can anyone help me how to make it work.

*** CamelRoute.java***

```
public class ConverterRoute implements RoutesBuilder {

    private static final String SOURCE_INPUT_PATH = "file://inbox?fileName=Source.txt";

    private static final String SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH = "file://outbox?fileName=file_$simple{date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.xml";

    @Override
    public void addRoutesToCamelContext(CamelContext context) throws Exception {
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                try {

                    DataFormat bindyFixed = new BindyCsvDataFormat(TestOne.class);

                    XmlFriendlyNameCoder nameCoder = new XmlFriendlyNameCoder("_-", "_");
                    Dom4JDriver dom4JDriver = new Dom4JDriver(nameCoder);

                    XStreamDataFormat xStreamDataFormat = new XStreamDataFormat();
                    xStreamDataFormat.setAliases(Collections.singletonMap("TEST_ONE", TestOne.class.getCanonicalName()));
                    //xStreamDataFormat.setXstreamDriver(dom4JDriver);

                    from(SOURCE_INPUT_PATH).
                            log("Received input from file and body is ${body}").
                            split().tokenize(System.lineSeparator()).
                            unmarshal(bindyFixed).
                            marshal(xStreamDataFormat).
                            log("After Marshalling and body is ${body}").
                            to(SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH).log("Finished Transformation").
                      end();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***TestOne.java***

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\\|", skipField = true)
public class TestOne{

    @DataField(pos = 3, required = true)
    private String testId;

    @Link
    private TestTwo testTwo;

}
```

***TestTwo.java***

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\\|", skipField = true)
public class TestTwo{

    @DataField(pos = 3, required = true)
    private String mockIt;

}
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyCsvFactory.setDefaultValuesForFields(BindyCsvFactory.java:695) ~[camel-bindy-2.24.1.jar:2.24.1]
```

Added the converter route details How I'm transforming the unstructured data to xml.

Comment: You've not shown your route so I'm not sure how you are doing this. Are you reading a stream source more than once, such as HTTP or file? If so, the second time it fails because you've used the source already, so you would need to enable stream caching. If this is all within the same marshal, then I presume it's using up a record for Test1 and therefore the record isn't there for Test2. If you try with a source containing multiple records do you get it to work but read Test2 from the second record?

Comment: @Screwtape I just added the converter route code how I'm transforming.

Comment: @Screwtape I’m not using multiple routes to do transformations.